# Multiple headers for a table wx Python

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Howdi folks, I have recently started dabbling in WX widgets using Python and would like to seek some direction on a task I want to achieve. The challenge here is to have a table with multiple headers i.e. headers spanning multi-lines with logical grouping. To show an example:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|        header_main_1      |     header_main_2     |
-----------------------------------------------------
| sub_1       |  sub_2      |  sub_3     |   sub_4  |
-----------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
| data1       |  data2      |  data3     |   data4  |
-----------------------------------------------------
| data5       |  data6      |  data7     |   data8  |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Here, `header_main_1` is the main header which encompasses two more headers `sub_1` and `sub_2`. Similarly with `header_main_2`. What follows is the data. The headers are clickable so that data can be sorted etc.

Is there any component/tutorial out there which touches on such a layout? If not and if I have to create it on my own, any tips on how should I go about doing it? Is there any option on grid to trigger this behaviour?

TIA,
sasuke

Comment: What have you tried? What type of data are you displaying? Will the data be static or sortable?

Comment: @acattle: The data source is pretty flexible; eventually it will be represented as list of lists or any format which the wx grid accepts. Yes, the columns have to be sortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can span cells with the grid control. There are examples in the wxPython demo package. However, you cannot have the labels in the columns themselves span across multiple columns. I think the cell spanning will get you most of the way there though. The columns will continue to be sortable. If you want the two columns on the right to sort without affecting the columns on the left, then you'll have to add that logic yourself or create two grids and put them next to each other.

Comment: Thanks, sounds a bit complicated but I'll give it a try and post updates here.

Comment: @sasuke what is your progress on this?